# TCP binding without a priori knowledge of processes bound

Tags: c, linux, ipc, cortex-m, uclinux

Before reading further, the following applies exclusively to an MMUless (cortex-m*) part running an embedded Linux and heavily modified kernel.

I have a very specific reason* for asking this, but I think the question in general is much more interesting:

0) This is necessarily applicable to a specif service I am writing, though any extension or abstraction would be interesting.

1) Suppose I am an instantiation of a process and I know there may be previous or future instantiations of the process that is the same as me. I am passed a unique** argument which tells me that I'm instantiation *i* where *i* is restricted to a set [0 - (*N*-1)] for a total *N* possible instantiations. Based on *i*, I am able to register with a configuration service and request current parameters on how the I, the *i*th instantiation, must behave. Further, I use *i* deterministically to create a TCP port, among other parameters not pertinent here, to which I must bind.

***So, the question is***: **knowing only my desired TCP port (derived from my argument** *i*,whether relevant or not), how could I tell if any other process is bound to the same TCP port?**

Of course a failed bind can be handled, but for my application... and the question in general, what would be the most efficient test in C for an already bound port before trying to bind? Or better put, I'd like to know if a bind will fail rather than attempt a bind and handle the failure.

*I'm using a certain library*** and nommu uC that causes all hell when two processes try to bind to the same port on the same transport protocol--I have no idea why, and I have no time to figure it out.

**I believe certain conditions could rarely arise in which two instantiations may be spawned asynchronously with the same argument which should provide unique and exclusive identification; given the process and the system architecture, each instantiation of this process must be contiguous and, therefore, unique. Should two instantiations with the identical argument be started, one must die with minimal and process-limited logic and operations.

***I'm using uCLibc, but the library I mention is a bit more obscure.

Comment: Why can't you just try to bind to the port?

Comment: Looking at the implementations of things like netstat or lsof will give you some idea how to query this. On Linux, there's also digging around /proc.

Comment: To immibis: Yes! I'm right there with you! I'd usually do this and then failover to some predetermined condition. The problem is that the library I'm using kills the kernel on a failed bind; I know this is globally bad, and the library shouldn't react as such, but my problem is minimal time to generate huge revenue. Yeah, so bind() should error out and set errno if it fails, but in this specific library irrevocable evil ensues... and under certain conditions could result in bricking.

Comment: To pvg: Thanks, brother. I'm really trying to avoid fopen() and popen() as a matter of convention, though I may need to make an exception here. I'm running on a single core, Linux, and 150 MHz, so any efficient gains (or avoided losses?) are crucial; our uC is over-stressed as it is ;-).

Answer (score 1):

> knowing only my desired TCP port (derived from my argument** i,whether relevant or not), how could I tell if any other process is bound to the same TCP port?

Just (try to) `connect()` to it.

Comment: Can't. The library which provides a layer 7 abstraction breaks the kernel (no panic, just evil) if it attempts to bind to a bound port. I attribute this to the cortex-m[n] architecture, given there's no mmu.

Comment: Hmm, my first comment was knee-jerk, I could attempt a connect: if it succeeds, the port is bound; if it fails, the port is likely not bound. Either way, I connect, no matter the outcome, then close the connection and proceed accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse /proc/net/tcp and see if the port is in use. Here there is a detailed description of each field: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/proc_net_tcp.txt

Digging aroud I discovered that is possible to use the functions of the TCP/IP stack in Linux, those that are used to generate the /proc/net/tcp.
This is a link to a project for a kernel module ([knetstat](https://github.com/veithen/knetstat/blob/master/knetstat.c)) that provide information about TCP sockets in human readable form. I understand that this approach may be impossible to integrate in your application, however, these information may be relevant to better understand the problem.

Comment: Part 1 , due to comment length limitation:

This is probably what I'll do. My uC is very slow, NOMMU (cortex-m[n]), and I need to maximize efficiency through my logic, as I don't trust GCC's optimizations *only in this product* since we're at the bleeding edge with our technology (and market standing) and need reasonable expectation for 5+ year lifespans for our products. See part 2...

Comment: Part 2: We operate on volume sales for both legacy and new generation devices; we always sell by the 1,000s, except for pilot programs. For legacy devices, though this matter is subtle since intrinsically the technology alters the company line as our new technology is solid, yet both untested in every configuration though readily available; so, I need to know the bound as ~instantaneously as possible given the need for deterministic operations which are handicapped by low clockspeed (minimal power requirements)... part 3

Comment: Part 3:and intrinsic asynchrony throughout an arbitrary topology--with no guarantee that our product, while compatible, is exclusive.